# PHP Receive JSON but can't decode it

Tags: php, json, post, decode

I receive JSON code in PHP but if I try to decode it nothing happens.

CODE:

```
$json = stripslashes($_POST['json']);
$output = json_decode($json);
```

When I log `$json` and `$output` to the console:

`$json` value is :

`{"post":"{'newfavorite':'<div id="1" class="favorite"><sub class="minID">Id 1</sub><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PXQpWm_kq0">http://www.youtu</a><span onclick="movefavorite(1)"><img class="move" title="Move" src="icon/move.png"></span><span onclick="removefavorite(1)"><img class="delete" title="Delete" src="icon/del.png"></span></div>','username':'ifch0o'}"}`

$output value is : empty string or null or undefined. I don't know.

Console says : `output is :`

Comment: The JSON is invalid; you have improperly nested quotes

Comment: the json input is not valid. PHP can't validate it, and nor can any other JSON decoder from any other language. Paste your code into a validator like [this one](http://jsonlint.com/) for proof.

Comment: you shouldn't have to call stripslashes as well ... this will destroy json's escaping.

Comment: the lesson here is to use a proper json encoder to generate the json rather than building it yourself. you need to fix the input; there's nothing you can do at the PHP end to fix it. (if this json is coming from a third party, then you need to moan at them for not being very good)

Comment: That what you call JSON is not a valid JSON since it has invalid format. There are many errors. That is why it can not be decoded. Check here http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ . Always do it before asking someone else what is happening.

Comment: validate your json first. you can use sites like: http://jsonlint.com/ to make sure that your json is valid.

Comment: @Orangepill - that depends on whether magic quotes is enabled. But I'd hope it isn't (in which case, your're right).

Comment: This JSON is valid if slashes aren't stripped...

Comment: Still, it makes no sense to wrap HTML into JSON. Send meaningful data [id's, links, and so], without the markup burden.

Comment: I don't think even if the slashes weren't stripped that it would be valid JSON. Per the [JSON Spec](http://www.json.org/) strings are supposed to be wrapped in double quotes not single quotes...

Comment: @War10ck They are wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON uses `"` to denote strings however your content contains `"` e.g.

`<div id="1" class="favorite">`

Because you have removed the character escaping using `stripslashes()` the strings are ending early and this is creating invalid JSON.

Simply remove `stripslashes()` to keep those characters escaped.

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
$output = json_decode($json);
```

This is how PHP sees your JSON:

```
{
   "post": "{'newfavorite':'<div id=",
   1 // Error here - unexpected 1
   " class=" // unexpected string
   ...
}
```